# How do I disable Tomcat compression for certain files to serve brotli compressed content?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jboss, brotli

I need to disable the Tomcat compression for just some files.

We have [`org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION` set to `on`](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/sysprops.html) to compress various files, some of those in other wars so turning that to `off` is not a real option.

I could find many guides on how to enable compression, but it doesn't seem to be quite often to disable it.

We need to disable it to serve some brotli precompressed font/css/js files which currently get compressed again with gzip due to tomcat not knowing about `Content-Encoding: br`, compressing and overwriting it with `Content-Encoding: gzip`.

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet but created a pull request that should solve it in the future: https://github.com/apache/tomcat/pull/99 . But I don't think that I can use both the default compress mechanism of tomcat and brotli compressed content :-(

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in Tomcat that will be **[fixed](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1824297) in Version 9.0.6**.